# What is an example of a lisse Weil sheaf which is not mixed?

Tags: weights, l-adic-sheaves

Fix a base field $\mathbf{F}_q$. What is a simple example of a lisse Weil sheaf which is not $\tau$-mixed for any identification $\tau: \overline{\mathbf{Q}_\ell} \cong \mathbf{C}$?

**Addendum**: it seems there are differing conventions about whether a weight can be any real number. An integrality condition is assumed in Deligne's Weil II, but not in more recent references.

I am hoping to see an example of a lisse sheaf which is non-mixed for reasons other than just its weights not being integral. Ideally, it would be an $\ell$-adic local system (with an action of the full $\pi_1(X,\overline{x})$).

Comment: Can't you just take $X = Spec \mathbb{F}_q$ and $L$ a local system with Frobenius action given by multiplication by 7 say ... this won't be $\tau$-mixed unless we're in characteristic 7 :)

Comment: Wouldn't this just give a single weight of $w = 2 \log_q(7)$, making it pure? The references I'm looking at don't seem to impose any kind of integrality conditions on $w$.

Comment: I'm not sure what references you are looking at. I'm looking at Deligne, Conjecture de Weil II, Définitions 1.2.1 and 1.2.2. My proposal is 1-dimensional, hence has to be pure, which it is not. Remark 5.1.2 in BBDG "faisceaux pervers" is potentially also helpful...

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson I'm looking at Kiehl-Weissauer, as well as two sets of notes based off of it, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1331/c7b0ff631b6f9e4d8937f19bd1b5eca84e31.pdf and https://web.math.princeton.edu/~takumim/Weil%20II.pdf

Comment: Definition 2.1 of I.2 in KW pg. 13 define weights, purity, and mixedness for any real β. Maybe more significantly, I'm not aware of any part of the proof of Weil II in KW (or the accompanying notes above) where the integrality of weights is needed. Is it used in Deligne's proof?